# jQuery Find Name Based On Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I am currently trying to fill a form using jQuery based on saved information. Currently, I am doing this:

```
$.each(form_data.form_data, function(name, val) {
    var $el = $('[name="' + val.name + '"]');

    var type = $el.attr('type');
    switch(type){
        case 'checkbox':
            $el.attr('checked', 'checked');
            break;
        case 'radio':
            $el.filter('[value="' + val.value + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
            break;
        default:
            $el.val(val.value);
    }
});
```

However, if the input field doesn't exist, I want to be able to copy the parent div and create a clone after the last div. The only time this would occur is if they dynamically created fields previously, so they would be in the format of `something-example[0]` and `something-example[1]`

My idea was if I had `something-example[2]`, then search for the input field without the square brackets so trying to match up `something-example` with `something-example`, and then clone that div. I am using Bootstrap if you want to get an understanding of the design of the page.
This is an example of the form-group:

```
<div class="form-group itemize-last">
        <label for="itemize-supplies-name[1]" class="col-sm-1">Item</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" name="itemize-supplies-name[1]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <label for="itemize-supplies-amount[1]" class="col-sm-1">Amount</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="text" name="itemize-supplies-amount[1]" class="form-control itemize-supplies-amount money">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How would I go about taking care of this feature? Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. What does "in the format of" mean?

Comment: Users are able to dynamically create form fields and save them to the database. When they go back, I want to be able to load all the information including the dynamically created fields. What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: If they're saved to the database, shouldn't they be generated server-side by your templating engine?

Comment: The server sends back a simple json of the information by the way.

Comment: Could you put together a semi-working jsFiddle? Here is one you can use to start: http://jsfiddle.net/vcdxcp5v/

Comment: @gibberish http://jsfiddle.net/vcdxcp5v/3/ this is the gist of what I have so far. I added example form data too. If it finds that $el is empty, I hope to have it check for the input name without the brackets, go to the parent form-group, copy it and place it after the last available one, and continue its merry way

Comment: The code in your fiddle is plagued with errors. Have you attempted to test/debug it? For starters, why are you using `form_data.form_data` instead of just `form_data`?

Comment: @ashin999: This will at least get the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/76484/vcdxcp5v/4/

Comment: @ashin999: You should use a templating engine (like http://handlebarsjs.com/). Also, if you want an amount and an item to be displayed together, they should belong to the same object in form_data.